# Minimum number of steps using only multiply A by 2, or divide A by 2 or increment A by one to go from number A to B

Tags: algorithm, numbers, time-complexity

Given two numbers `A` and `B`, what is the minimum number of steps to transform number A to become number B.
A step can either be `A *= 2`, `A++` or `A /= 2` if and only if A is an even number.

What is the most efficient algorithm to achieve this?
Suppose A and B can be really large numbers.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a typical question that you'd wake up wondering. Is it homework? Nonetheless, to make this more answerable, can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Are you saying that you can do (1) `A(n+1) = A(n) * 2` for any `A(n)`, (2) `A(n+1) = A(n) + 1` for any `A(n)`, or (3) `A(n+1) = A(n) / 2` only for even `A(n)`?

Comment: Can we assume `A < B` ?

Comment: just a quick silly idea: going from zero to A is number of ones in binary + number of bits-1 ... (so for each one you add `+=1` and for each bit you multiply `*=2`) so for going from A to B I would start experimenting with going from `0` to `(A-B) ` however not sure if that is minimal number of steps/moves/operations and this will work for `A>=B` for the case `A<B` I am not sure yet ... and its also not clear what number representation you got it is 2'os complement? how many bits? is it integer or fixed or floating point? as you do not have `-=1` operation this is tricky does `/=2` round down?

Comment: Suppose A<=B then you can use Binary search idea to transform A to B. The running time will be O(log B).

Comment: Say hello to your classmate: [Algorithm to find minimum number of moves to transform one number to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70902742/algorithm-to-find-minimum-number-of-moves-to-transform-one-number-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take, done in C#.

```
var a = 2;
var b = 15;

var found = new HashSet<int>() { a };

var operations = new (string operation, Func<int, bool> condition, Func<int, int> projection)[]
{
    ("/2", x => x % 2 == 0, x => x / 2),
    ("*2", x => x <= int.MaxValue / 2, x => x *2),
    ("+1", x => true, x => x + 1),
};

IEnumerable<(int count, string operations, int value)> Project((int count, string operations, int value) current)
{
    foreach (var operation in operations)
    {
        if (operation.condition(current.value))
        {
            var value = operation.projection(current.value);
            if (!found.Contains(value))
            {
                found.Add(value);
                yield return (current.count + 1, $"{current.operations}, {operation.operation}", value);
            }
        }
    }
}

var candidates = new[] { (count: 0, operations: $"{a}", value: a) };

while (!found.Contains(b))
{
    candidates =
        candidates
            .SelectMany(c => Project(c))
            .ToArray();
}

var result = candidates.Where(x => x.value == b).First();

Console.WriteLine($"{result.count} operations: {result.operations} = {result.value}");
```

That outputs:

```
5 operations: 2, +1, *2, +1, *2, +1 = 15
```

Basically, this is starting with `a` at the zeroth step. It then takes this generation and produces all possible values from the operations to create the next generation. If it produces a value that it has already seen it discards the value as there is an equal or faster operation to produce the value. It keeps repeating until `b` is found.